# Get a github folder it's contents as a json file

Tags: json, github, github-api, arduinojson

if I construct this URL, I can see the contents of the images folder as a json in Firefox.
https://api.github.com/repos/DessoCode/ESP32/contents/Images?ref=main

However, this doesn't seem to be a true json since my parser doesn't parse this. I'm using an ESP32 and Arduino.

The code works with a true json link. (For example: http://arduinojson.org/example.json)
My question is: How do I change the first URL so it has a .json extension?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I needed to serialize the input stream first, then I could deserialize it and use the values.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is to [install GitHub CLI `gh`](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation=) (through one of the [`linux_arm64` packages](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.11.3)), and use [`gh api`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api) to execute the API call... with `-q` or `--jq <string>` to query and select values from the response using [`jq` syntax](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters).
No need to serialize/de serialize.

```
gh api repos/DessoCode/ESP32/contents/Images?ref=main --jq ".[].path"

Images/robot.bmp
Images/skulltest.bmp
Images/yellow.bmp
```